# Choosing specific element in XPath

Tags: xpath, duplicates, element

I got 2 elements under the same name "reason". When i'm using `//*:reason/text()` it gives me both of the elements, but i need the first one. (not the one inside "details"). please help..

```
<xml xmlns:gob="http://osb.yes.co.il/GoblinAudit">
    <fault>
        <ctx:fault xmlns:ctx="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context">
            <ctx:errorCode>BEA-382500</ctx:errorCode>
            <ctx:reason>OSB Service Callout action received SOAP Fault response</ctx:reason>
            <ctx:details>
                <ns0:ReceivedFaultDetail xmlns:ns0="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/stages/transform/config">
                    <ns0:faultcode xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">soapenv:Server</ns0:faultcode>
                    <ns0:faultstring>BEA-380001: Internal Server Error</ns0:faultstring>
                    <ns0:detail>
                        <con:fault xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context">
                            <con:errorCode>BEA-380001</con:errorCode>
                            <con:reason>Internal Server Error</con:reason>
                            <con:location>
                                <con:node>RouteTo_FinancialControllerBS</con:node>
                                <con:path>response-pipeline</con:path>
                            </con:location>
                        </con:fault>
                    </ns0:detail>
                </ns0:ReceivedFaultDetail>
            </ctx:details>
            <ctx:location>
                <ctx:node>PipelinePairNode2</ctx:node>
                <ctx:pipeline>PipelinePairNode2_request</ctx:pipeline>
                <ctx:stage>set maintain offer</ctx:stage>
                <ctx:path>request-pipeline</ctx:path>
            </ctx:location>
        </ctx:fault>
    </fault>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `//` qualifier which will descend into any subtree and find all occurences of `reason`. You can try to be more specific about the subpath:

```
//fault/*:fault/*:reason/text()
```

This will only match the outer `reason` but not the inner `reason.`.

Answer (score 2):

> *"...but i need the first one"*

You can use position index to get the first matched `reason` element :

```
(//*:reason)[1]/text()
```

> *" (not the one inside "details")"*

The above can be expressed as *finding `reason` element which doesn't have ancestor `details`* :

```
//*:reason[not(ancestor::*:details)]/text()
```

For a large XML document, using more specific path i.e avoid `//` at the beginning, would results in a more efficient XPath :

```
/xml/fault/*:fault/*:reason/text()
```

But for a small XML, it's just a matter of personal preference, since the improvement is likely to be negligible.